# Mouse hover Coordinates in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mouseover

I have a figure window (made in a function file) on which I am getting the user input through ginput command. I want to get all the coordinates that my mouse moves over and use those coordinates to change some colors on my figure window.
for example. If my mouse moves over the screen I'd give command

```
if xCord > 80 && xCord < 100 && yCord> 40 && yCord < 80 
set(handle,'facecolor','g')
end
```

How shall I get all the points that my mouse moves or hovers over ?

Answer (score 0):

Basic moseover and  mouse position functionality is as follows:

```
figure()
set (gcf, 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @mouseover);

function [data] = mouseover(gcbo,eventdata,handles)
    c = get (gca, 'CurrentPoint'); % get mouse coordinates
    c
```